# Mic preamp, fixing noise and gain issues

Tags: noise, microphone, gain, preamp

I'm trying to fix a preamp (made by a colleague) that's noisy and somehow not amplifying enough.  I should say right away that this project is pushing the edge of my electronics knowledge so I have a lot of questions.  There's actually 2 copies on 2 boards, for one electret and one dynamic mics, but the design was the same except for the "plug-in power" for the electret (not phantom power, this expects about 5V, though I guess it's currently getting 12V).  This is the current circuit (only R3 is different between the 2 boards).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzLhRr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From my research I found a few things maybe should be done differently.  First, it seems it's mostly power line noise that I'm getting.  (I tried getting cleaner power supplies but on a small budget that didn't work out.)  Instead, I could add some filtering on the voltage divider, and on the electret bias circuit.  I also don't like the idea of attenuating after amplifying so I'd move the potentiometer to control the gain instead, as such:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2from5N.png)</sup>

But these changes mean I have to pretty much redo the whole thing, and the product is in a "finished" state (in a box with connectors and everything), so I'd like to minimize the changes if possible.
**1) (main question) I was wondering if "pre-filtering" the power supply would be equivalent/better/worse to having the filters in the preamp circuits?**
I was thinking for example adding a 2nd order RC filter on a separate little board.  It would reduce the voltage a bit, but I can use small resistors and then do one good filter instead of 3?

The other issue is the gain.  Note that the goal is to get line level audio, so that voice from the mics is at comparable volume to other sounds coming from a computer.  The outputs goes to speakers (this is part of an intercom/mixer).  The gain is already at 2k and still pretty weak.  I'm thinking maybe the electret mic isn't getting the appropriate power?  I think it's supposed to get around 5V, but I read in another thread something I didn't quite understand about the electret inner workings and how the resistor value would change how much amplitude it would output.
**2) Any tips on what value to use for the electret bias?**
Note that the dynamic mic board (without R3) also sounds weak, but I'll have to verify, its R5 might have a different value.

Finally, I also read about resistor noise and how I'm better off not going too high (and use metal film) with such high gains.  But I'm not sure which resistors would be most critical.  In the second schematic, I'm guessing R8, R4... Not sure if the voltage divider also, R3, R9/11?  Related to that, I'm unsure what values to use for the voltage divider.
**3) Other than not wasting too much power (prefer large values), or resistor noise (prefer low values), are there other factors to consider?**
Note that the dynamic mic has output impedance of 600Ω but the electret, 5kΩ.
**4) Should I "tune" the circuits differently, or just go with the highest one and give them about 50kΩ input impedance (R8)?**

Any other comments or tips on the circuit would be appreciated!

**5) In the second circuit, should the output after Cout be left "floating" or add a R to neutral, and if so what R value?**

Comment: What type of noise is it? What does it sound like, and is there any way to bandpass and find the frequency. This could help in localizing the problem in the circuit or possible within your full setup.

Comment: The noise actually sounds different with different power supplies, buzzes of various frequencies mostly, and goes away with a big (expensive) desktop regulated supply.  I also started testing adding a filter before the preamps with encouraging results, but some other parts in the same box didn't work with the filter.  I'm now getting ready to disassemble some more parts hence my post.

Comment: What type of condenser microphone are you using?  Is the gain adequate when used with a dynamic microphone?

Comment: To carry on with @ThreePhaseEel, also check the expected input on whatever equipment you're using to see what it can take. Also double check the preamp to make sure it can deal with 48V phantom power. I actually don't see phantom power. Can you verify?

Comment: @zorgkang Also, quick debug tip, plug the mic preamp in using a ground lifter. Getting rid of the ground return path can help. I would suggest not adding a filter before hand. You are essentially saying that the noise is in the mic or cable at that point. If that's the case, fix that, not the preamp. If you want to play with that, try different mics and better shielded cables.

Comment: Is this high fidelity audio? Or is the microphone only for voice capture (similar to telephone)? If the latter, you can raise the cutoff frequency of the microphone to 500 Hz or more by using a smaller AC coupling cap at the input. If your noise is low frequency, that should help a bit.

Comment: Looks like the first circuit has a gain of 2201.  Since the TL071 has a GBW of 3MHz that limits the bandwidth of the amplifier to under 1400 Hz.  Definitely not high fidelity.  The second circuit is better, but at the higher gains will still have limited bandwidth.  How much gain do you really need?

Comment: @Three I can't remember which was worse, but both were not loud enough.

Comment: @mcmiln There is no phantom power, sorry for not making that clear this is "plug-in-power" for an old Sony electret mic that was designed to plug into a video camera.  It expects around 5V I think.  That's the part clearly indicated "for electret mic only".  I did not understand your second comment.  I was talking about filtering the power supply not the mic signal.  I'll have to read on what a ground lifter might be...  Right now nothing is grounded in my preamp.  Finally I'll edit the question to clarify that the preamp should output at line level, it goes to speakers.

Comment: @mkeith It's for voice (an intercom).  The buzzes were not only low frequency though, would that filter the noise from the voltage divider too?  I thought C5 was needed for that.  I was actually thinking about that Cin cap after I posted.  Isn't it the wrong polarity in the electret configuration?  The electret gets 12V while the other side is about 6V?  Or I'm missing something basic about polarized capacitors?

Comment: @John That seems very relevant, but I have no idea how GBW (gain bandwidth?) works.  I'll have to read up on that.  I need the gain that will make the voice sound at a "normal" volume at line level.  Specifically, there's a switch that interrupts other line level audio coming from a computer when I wish to speak in the intercom, so the voice level needs to be comparable (audible and not too loud).

Comment: I am referring to the original schematic. I would suggest changing Cin to a much smaller cap. There is no reason to amplify all the low frequency sound. I believe 0.022uF will set your low frequency limit at 300 Hz, which should be reasonable. I don't see any reason to add resistance on the output. So I would get rid of R6 and R7 for sure, at least for test purposes. (Replace them with shorts). Where does the output go to, anyway? Maybe those resistors are for short-circuit protection? The gain does seem excessively high, but since you say the signal is weak, let's keep it high, for now.

Comment: Oh, are you sure you have the polarity correct on the microphone? Condenser microphones have DC polarity.

Comment: For an intercom circuit a few kHz of bandwidth is probably OK, still the second circuit is better (assuming the pot is actually connected as a variable resistor, the schematic doesn't show that).  You can find out about gain bandwidth in any reference on op-amps.  If there's anything that's not clear you can always start a new question here.

Comment: @John Yes I realized after posting how the pot is supposed to get drawn in the circuit.  I'll fix that in both circuits.

Comment: I am sorry, the question is very long and i am too lazy to read it all. But i do know that biasing a microphone may be much cleaner, if you use opamp that buffers a voltage reference. Take a look at MAX9814. They show exactly that in diagram.

Comment: @zorgkang Did you ever try a dynamic? I might be wrong here, but I was pretty sure solid state condensers don't work without phantom. It's possible you have some power being fed to the mic giving you small signals, but not enough (unless you have a tube mic). --Interesting wiki on electrets. Phantom not needed but many preamps use it for them. And is there a battery in this mic? If so, check the voltage and see if it needs replacing.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks.  Which components make this high-pass filter with Cin?  From the numbers you give I think it's the 22k bias resistor, but that would only filter that bias power no?  Wouldn't the same power supply noise come through the voltage divider?  And the mic signal would not get the same filter (probably depends instead on it's output impedance)?  As for the output, it's to speakers with a TRS connector, so I think you're right it must have been for short protection.  No clue how much R is needed for that though, or what the risk is.  Again, more reading to do on that.

Comment: @zorgkang And a ground lifter just gets rid of ground. Essentially if you took a three pronged plug and ripped the third plug off. It's not a bad thing if you're careful and is often done in highly cramped studio spaces. You can even get rid of amp buzz like that. All a matter of return current.

Comment: @mcmiln Check PiP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_power#Other_microphone_powering_techniques.  And again, the other board without R3 is for a dynamic mic.  I'll do some more tests today to clarify the differences between the two boards.

Comment: @mcmiln Thanks for the ground lifter clarification.  But as I said, nothing grounded currently, just using + and - of the psu as per the circuit.  That's actually yet another thing I'm wondering: what to ground if anything.  Was leaning towards only grounding shielding on box and cables, if it helps.

Comment: Referring to the first schematic, Cin, R1 and R2 form a high-pass filter. The time constant is Cin * the parallel resistance of R1 and R2. So, it is Cin * 47k/2.

Comment: I made several suggestions in one of my comments. Did you try any of them? I know you want to understand what is going on, but you also want to fix the problem, right? I tried to suggest things that  were  relatively easy to try.

Comment: @mkeith Yes thanks, I will try a different cap.  Haven't had time yet is all.  I did verify the polarity of the mic, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too long to read, so I'm only responding to the schematic.  It's not clear which schematic you are asking about, so I grabbed the first one.  To keep this answer consistent if the question is edited, here is the schematic:

[image]

1. 12 V is quite high for driving a electret microphone.  3-5 V is more normal.  Check the datasheet.

   22 kΩ is quite high for driving a electret microphone.  Did you even look at the datasheet?

   Noise on the supply will be directly coupled onto the input via R3.

   C4 and R5 form a high pass filter at 1.6 kHz that affects the overall frequency response of the amp.  Frequencies below 1.6 kHz will have less gain.  This makes no sense.  Rolling off gain below 20 Hz is fine and is still considered "HiFi" audio.  Rolling off at 100 Hz or so can be acceptable in some cases.  Rolling of at 1.6 kHz is just bad.

   You are asking for way too much gain from a single stage.  The gain you are trying to achieve (above the 1.6 kHz high pass) is (R4+R5)/R5 = 2.2k, which is absurd for a single stage.  Let's say you only care about frequencies up to 10 kHz (HiFi goes to twice that), and you want 10x gain headroom for the feedback to work well.  You are expecting the gain bandwidth product of the opamp to be 2,200*(10 kHz)*10 = 220 MHz.  Even without the factor of 10 for the feedback that's way out of line.

   R6 makes non sense at all.  I can't even guess what you think it does, but what it actually does is waste 1/2 the gain.

   The volume control on the output isn't a good idea, especially when you are expecting such a very large gain.  Loud signals will clip before you can attenuate them with the volume control.

To fix points 1-3, use a resistor divider to make the right voltage for the electret.  20 kΩ on top and 10 kΩ at bottom will divide the supply by 3 to make 4 V, which is probably in the intended range of the electret.  To filter out supply noise, break the top 20 kΩ resistor into two 10 kΩ resistors and put a cap to ground between them.  The divider impedance at the cap is 10 kΩ//20 kΩ = 6.7 kΩ.  That requires at least 1.2 µF for the rolloff frequency to be 20 Hz or less.  You seem to have a bunch of 10 µF caps around, which would work well.

Connect the + side of the electret to the junction of the bottom two resistors.  This drives the electret with 4 V at a dynamic impedance of 5 kΩ, which is a lot better than the existing circuit.

To fix the gain, it's good to start with what the opamp can do.  The TL071 has a *typical* gain*bandwidth of 3 MHz.  Let's say we want a gain of 10 headroom for the feedback to work well, so that leaves 300 kHz.  Assuming HiFi audio, the gain should be flat to 20 kHz.  That leaves a gain of (300 kHz)/(20 kHz) = 15.  This was based on the typical, not minimum guaranteed gain.  However, the factor of 10 for the feedback isn't exact.  If it's only 5 at 20 kHz the closed loop gain will still be reasonably flat, so lets aim for 15x voltage gain.

15x voltage gain means R4/R5 = 14.  Keeping the existing R4 means R5 should be 1.57 kΩ, so 1.6 kΩ it is.  The C4-R5 filter should roll off at 20 Hz or lower, which means C4 must be 5 µF or more.  Keep the 10 µF.

With a sane gain, you need extra stages to get line level and beyond.  One advantage of this is that you can leave the volume control where it is, immediately after the first stage.  The signals in the first stage won't be large enough to cause problems, even when very loud.  10 mV from a microphone would be a lot, which times 15 is only 150 mV, so that's all fine.

Or work it backwards.  The TL071 might be able to swing 8 Vpp in this setup.  That divided by 15 means it won't clip as long as the input is 500 mVpp.  No electret or dynamic mic is going to put out that much.

Comment: Thanks @Olin.  Your answer is as long as my question, only took 2 minutes to read carefully ;).  A previous comment did point the gain bandwidth issue.  I think I understand all you've said, but wouldn't the the power supply noise be also coming through R1/R2?  That's why I had added C5 (and R8) in the second diagram.

Comment: @zorg: If done right, R1//R2 should be high enough impedance so that whatever is coming thru Cin swamps any power supply noise.  Doing what you did in the second schematic doesn't hurt other than add complexity, might help a little.  I'd fix this by making R1 and R2 larger.  After all, they only need to overcome the leakage current of the opamp input, which is quite small for this amp.  1 MOhm each sounds about right.  Noise is definitely coming from the supply thru R3 though, which you need to fix.  That's why I said to use a divider and break the top resistor in two to allow for filtering.

Comment: Regarding 12V on the electret, to make a long story short, the voltage divider idea doesn't work well.  The mic itself makes a divider with R3.  I found through testing that I get the best output from the mic with 12V supply (tested 3 to 12 with clean supply) and 43k (tested 0 to 50k), which gives 4V across the mic.  I'll have to test further to figure out how much gain I need and where filtering is required, based on your and other's suggestions.  (And I don't have a datasheet, it's a Sony mic, I found few specs for it.  Had to resort to testing.)